# Bluetooth permanently on in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

Just updated 14.04 and now bluetooth is permanently on.

1. Disabling on the bar does not work;
2. Disabling via the System Settings menu does not work either;
3. I already had, before the update, set `InitiallyPowered = false` in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`;
4. Issuing the command `$ rfkill block bluetooth` does not work (also tried with `sudo`);
5. I've rebooted after the update, twice, but did not help either.

I'd like to have it switched off on boot, but still be able to enable it when I need it. Any solutions?

Comment: Update: for some reason nothing I tried was working but  an ubuntu update must have fixed the issue since the button now works fine and the state is saved across reboots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

`rfkill block bluetooth`

into

`/etc/rc.local`

before

`exit 0`

command.

To disable the bluetooth driver from loading on startup:

`sudo $EDITOR /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

add:

`blacklist btusb`

Enabling it later should just be:

`sudo modprobe btusb`